# When embedding a YouTube video with a playlist how can the next video not autoplay?

Tags: video, youtube, embed, video-hosting

Is there a way to stop autoplay of the next playlist video upon completion of the currently embedded video?

I just want to play the one that's embedded but nothing else.

Comment: Why don't you grab the direct link to this video and remove the `list=` parameters which is used for playlist?

Answer (score 2):

[This article has a way to disable the related that play at the end of the current video](http://brianwong.com/blog/youtube-embed-code-autoplay/): You have to add a `rel=0` parameter to the embed URL.

For example:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/R0V_D4zaEpU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```